# How can I enable streaming (flush/ob_flush) in CentOS 8 stream with PHP-FPM?

Tags: centos, php, fastcgi, fpm

I have a new install of CentOS 8 Stream with Apache and PHP-FPM setup using all defaults (this defaults to PHP 7.2.24 FPM/FastCGI).

My application uses [Server Sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) using JavaScripts `EventSource` object. To have that working I need the Apache/FPM setup to be able to send data to the client when it is available (or at least when PHP's `flush` call is made).

However, FPM does not do that. It will only output all data as soon as the script has finished. (Which is not what I want ...)

How can I configure PHP-FPM on Centos8 so that it can flush data during processing of the script?

I tried adding a `Proxy` directive in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf`:

```
<Proxy "fcgi://localhost" enablereuse=on flushpackets=on max=10>
</Proxy>
```

right after `</FilesMatch>`, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question, but a (temporary) work-around: disable PHP-FPM and switch back to `mod_php`.

In CentOS 8, this is fairly simple, in `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf`, uncomment this line:

```
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```

and comment out the line for `mpm_event`.

Then add this to `httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
        StartServers              5
        MinSpareServers           5
        MaxSpareServers           10
        MaxRequestWorkers         150
        MaxConnectionsPerChild    0
</IfModule>
```

Source: https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-apache-web-server-centos-8/